# Doubled log messages in python

Tags: python-3.x, logging

Lets say we have such a structure of project:

-main.py

-dir_1/module_log.py

where module_log.py is set o helpers to avoid redundant code in project.

Content of the module_log.py is as follows:

```
import logging as log

def get_module_logger(module_name):
   logger = log.getLogger(module_name)
   logger.setLevel(log.INFO)

   formatter = log.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')

   file_handler = log.FileHandler('path/to/logfile/logs.log')
   file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

   stream_handler = log.StreamHandler()
   stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

   logger.addHandler(file_handler)
   logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

   return logger

 def log_info_1():
    logger = get_module_logger(__name__)
    logger.info('\n____________INFO_1____________')

 def log_info_2():
    logger = get_module_logger(__name__)
    logger.info('\n____________INFO_2____________')
```

And content of the main.py is like:

```
import module_log as ml

ml.log_info_1()
logger = ml.get_module_logger(__name__)
logger.info('Main log')
ml.log_info_2()
```

The problem is that the logger logs properly first and second message into file, but the third one is written twice.

Could anyone explain my why is it so? How to avoid such issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short version

The reason for that is because you register to the same logger the same file \ stream handler more than once.

### Long version

In your `dir_1/module_log.py` module, you define two functions `log_info_1` and `log_info_2`.
Each of these functions in turn calls the `get_module_logger` function **with the same module name** (in your case `__name__ = "dir_1.module_log"` )

The `get_module_logger` registers to the same logger (with that name) two handlers with a formatter.

That logger name is defined "globally" across the python interpreter running your program. so in case you want to get that definition of logger with name `<name>` you can just call `logging.getLogger(<name>)` from anywhere in your code and use it freely.

To correct your code, you need to assign handlers to that logger *once* and then you can use it anywhere.

```
def get_module_logger(module_name):

   logger = log.getLogger(module_name)
   logger.setLevel(log.INFO)

   if not len(logger.handlers):
       formatter = log.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')

       file_handler = log.FileHandler('path/to/logfile/logs.log')
       file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

       stream_handler = log.StreamHandler()
       stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

       logger.addHandler(file_handler)
       logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

   return logger
```

Comment: You're right. Thanks a lot. I suspected that two instances were created, but I didn't know which condition was needed.